# A script on this page may be busy Error in VS2010 ASP.net WebForm

Tags: runtime-error, busy-waiting

I developed a website in VS 2010 , now I want to run it in VS2013, but for just some oages when I want to run it from VS using FireFox ,this Error is shown.
My projects is ASP.net webForm.

```
  A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. 
  You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue
```

the similar error is in Chrome, IE , ...

whats the problem? I searched on net even this site, but couldn't Fix the Error.

Answer (score 0):

This basically means that your browser thinks that one (or more) scripts on the page is taking an unreasonable amount of time to complete its execution. Alternatively it could be caused by malware or certain browser plug-ins. Try starting Firefox in "Safe Mode". If the problem persists, the fault is on your end.

Comment: the problem is this Error occurs on all browsers, and just in some pages. I updated FireFox, and still have this Error.I press Shift Key(for disabling Add_ons) but Still Error :(

Comment: Then you need to look at what the JavaScript on the pages in question are doing. Google Chrome has a built-in JavaScript debugger. Using it might identify the offending section of code.